# Why does hello.do redirect when .do is not a TLD?

Tags: tld

I was recently playing around and typed in hello.do to see if .do was a TLD. It redirected me to a page in both firefox and chrome but .do is not a TLD so I'm confused as to why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ah. Found it: ".DO is the country code domain for the Dominican Republic..." https://www.eurodns.com/international-domain-names/do-domain-registration/

Comment: Thanks, My hosting provider just didn't include it which confused me!